# Retrieve data from database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to get data from database by using ajax. The data will be fetched by choosing the drop down option and click the search button and data will show up in the table. I've written the proper query and it runs very well. All I want is just show the data from database to the table with ajax. I've read tutorials and questions in Stackoverflow but still got no solution. Here's the sample of interface, [image: user interface]

Here's my controller :

```
function getDataExcelKK() {
    $station = $this->input->get('station'); 

    $data = $this->M_dbstatmanagement->getDataExcelKK($station);
    $this->load->view('v_lhastat_admin', $data);
}
```

The model :

```
function getDataExcelKK($station) {
    $this->db->select("F.NAMA_FILE AS NAMA_FILE, DATE_FORMAT(F.TANGGAL_UPLOAD, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS TANGGAL_UPLOAD");
    $this->db->from("fileupload F");
    $this->db->join("user U", "F.ID_USER = U.ID_USER");
    $this->db->where("U.DOMISILI", $station); 
    $this->db->order_by("F.TANGGAL_UPLOAD DESC");

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

The view (table) :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-checkable order-column" id="lhaStatAdmin">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="10%">No.</th>
                            <th width="10%">File Name</th>
                            <th width="10%">Upload Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="isi-data">
                        <?php 
                        $no = 1;
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach($getExcelFromKK as $key => $row) {?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['NAMA_FILE'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['TANGGAL_UPLOAD'];?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And here's my ajax :

```
    $('#button-search').on('click', function() {
    var station = $('#stationChoose').val();

    $.ajax({
        async       : true,
        type        : 'GET',
        url         : '<?php echo base_url();?>sms/getDataExcelKK', 
        data        : {"station": station},
        success     : 
            function(data) {
                $('#isi-data').html(data);

            }
    });
});
```

UPDATE : Instead of retrieve data into table, I got a table inside table when I click 'Search' button.[image: user interface double table]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, keep url in double quotes.

```
$('#button-search').on('click', function() {
    var station = $('#stationChoose').val();

    $.ajax({
        async       : true,
        type        : 'GET',
        url         : "<?php echo base_url();?>sms/getDataExcelKK", 
        data        : {"station": station},
        success     : 
            function(data) {
                $('#isi-data').html(data);

            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you try to console the data recieved from ajax page. or you may also try to set async to false.

Answer (score 0):

try those in your success in ajax

```
var preparedString = '';
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   var preparedString += '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+(i+1)+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].NAMA_FILE+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].TANGGAL_UPLOAD+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>'
}
$('#isi-data').append(preparedString);
```

so your ajax should look like this

```
$('#button-search').on('click', function() {
var station = $('#stationChoose').val();

$.ajax({
    async       : true,
    type        : 'GET',
    url         : '<?php echo base_url();?>sms/getDataExcelKK', 
    data        : {"station": station},
    success     : 
        function(data) {
            var preparedString = '';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                var preparedString += '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+(i+1)+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].NAMA_FILE+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].TANGGAL_UPLOAD+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>'
            }
            $('#isi-data').append(preparedString);
        }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your reply but could I just using the table as written in html instead of in ajax? Because next I want every table row become clickable to open modal.

Answer (score 0):

you ether create the html from you data and append it(as @Ivan Tabaka sed) or you create your html in the PHP and append it in your html

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to load full table in another view(ex.'table.php') and deposit this view on by replacing previous full table (can apply datatable in table.php) , after that  for  every table row become clickable to open modal, every tr become `<tr onclick="action(3)">`.

```
  script:
  function action(argument) {
            // body...
            alert(argument);
        }
```

Comment: So I need to create a new table view and then parsing to the main view with `<div id='example'>`?

Comment: yes , hence our previous table remove from DOM and new will be arrive with new searched result with datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try to set async to false.

```
$.ajax({
    async       : false,
    type        : 'GET',
    url         : "<?php echo base_url();?>sms/getDataExcelKK", 
    data        : {"station": station},
    success     : 
        function(data) {
            $('#isi-data').html(data);

        }
});
```